# Move constructors and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, move-semantics, move-constructor

### Synopsis

How can I safely design a move constructor when a class uses multiple inheritance?

### Details

Consider the following scenario:

```
struct T { };
struct U { };

struct X : public T, public U
{
    X(X&& other)
      : T(std::move(other))
      , U(std::move(other)) // already moved?!
    {
    }
};
```

Is there a way to move-construct both `T` and `U` safely?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**tl;dr**: the code in the question is ok.

The code above is fine, because `std::move` itself doesn't actually change `other` in any way, it just does a cast to make `other` into an rvalue reference so that the move constructors of `T` and `U` are called instead of their copy constructors.

When `T(std::move(other))` is run, `T`'s move constructor will be called (assuming it has one) and the `T` in `other` will be moved to the `T` in `this`. The `U` in `other` will be left alone until the `U(std::move(other))` is run.

Note that this means that when your move constructor code for `X` runs, you cannot rely on the members/member functions of `T` and `U` in `other`, as those bits of `other` will have already have been moved.

---

As a side note, it could be improved by being changed to:

```
X(X&& other)
  : T(std::move(static_cast<T&>(other)))
  , U(std::move(static_cast<U&>(other)))
{
}
```

because this version doesn't rely on the implicit upcast from `X&&` to `T&&`/`U&&`. Relying on the implicit upcast can be a problem because `T` and/or `U` may have a `T(X&&)` constructor or an accept-anything template constructor, either of which would get picked instead of the `T(T&&)` move constructor that you really want to call.

Comment: until someone in calls a virtual function or something in a move constructor/assignment operator which is addressed by another class in inheritance tree... rihgt?

Comment: Why not `T(static_cast<T&&>(other))` rather than `T(std::move(static_cast<T&>(other)))` (and the same for `U`)?

Comment: @ildjarn that would also work if `T` is a concrete class, but could be a problem if `T` was a template parameter because of reference collapsing. I was trying to avoid "inlining" std::move to make it clearer what I was changing

Comment: @VladLazarenko correct - so don't call virtual functions in your move constructors :-)

Comment: There are no templates in this example, and if there were you would probably want `std::forward` rather than `std::move`. I think using `move` here confuses things, personally, but I see what you're getting at. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn i'm not sure what you're getting at with `std::forward`, but then i'm not even sure whether you're thinking of a template constructor or a template class. My point about reference collapsing was a dud, because even if T and U were template args, they'd have to be real classes as they're inherited from. Still, since we are doing a move, I think it's clearer to do the explicit upcast and the move separately. It also encourages the use of `std::move` for doing lvalue-to-rvalue conversions over writing casts manually, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: You brought up reference collapsing, so it was assumed that you meant a template constructor. In any case, like I said, I see what you're getting at, I just think it's extra noise if there's a `static_cast<>` already.

Comment: @ildjarn yeah, I accidentally confused things by bringing up reference collapsing. Granted, if it was a template constructor you'd probably want `std::forward`. But since the original question was about move constructors, and I can't see any sane way for a move constructor to be a template, this is getting a bit offtopic :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can I use other object in sidetone constructor body after using moving it  like:

```
struct T { };
struct U { };

struct X : public T, public U
{
    X(X&& other)
      : T(std::move(other))
      , U(std::move(other)) // already moved?!
    {
    member1 = other.member1; //something like. 

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is fine, as the answer from @je4d explained it.

You could also write it this way :

```
X(X&& other)
  : T(static_cast<T&&>(other))
  , U(static_cast<T&&>(other))
{
}
```

See the comment of the answer from @jead for explanation.